# How can I share an Eclipse workspace between accounts in Mac?

Tags: eclipse, macos, osx-lion, workspace, user-accounts

I basically want to create an Eclipse workspace that can be accessed between accounts on my Mac. I'm currently running Mac OS X v10.7.1. **The other caveat is that I want to be able to do use Git on that workspace so I can push and pull from both accounts. If this is not possible, I'm ok with switching accounts to do the Git stuff.**

Is it possible to create an Eclipse workspace that can be accessed between 2 accounts in Mac OS X Lion? Do both accounts need to be admin or not? If this is actually possible, how would I go about setting this up?

Here's some more info about my accounts (both admin, I think?)...

```
$ id HristoOskov
uid=501(HristoOskov) gid=20(staff) groups=20(staff),403(com.apple.sharepoint.group.2),404(com.apple.sharepoint.group.3),402(com.apple.sharepoint.group.1),401(com.apple.access_screensharing),12(everyone),33(_appstore),61(localaccounts),79(_appserverusr),80(admin),81(_appserveradm),98(_lpadmin),100(_lpoperator),204(_developer)

$ id dev
uid=502(dev) gid=20(staff) groups=20(staff),403(com.apple.sharepoint.group.2),404(com.apple.sharepoint.group.3),402(com.apple.sharepoint.group.1),502(access_bpf),401(com.apple.access_screensharing),12(everyone),33(_appstore),61(localaccounts),79(_appserverusr),80(admin),81(_appserveradm),98(_lpadmin),100(_lpoperator),204(_developer)
```

... and how the directory that I want to have Eclipse use as a workspace...

```
$ ll
drwxr-xr-x   4 dev  staff   136 Sep 16 18:38 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 39 dev  staff  1326 Sep 17 03:59 ..
drwxr-xr-x   4 dev  admin   136 Sep 17 03:24 myWorkspace
```

---

### What I've tried...

So I tried making the directory that I want to put the workspace in owned by `root` but then Eclipse complains when I try to create a project...

```
Creation Problems
Parent of resource: /Users/HristoOskov/Sites/random is marked as read-only.
```

Then I realized that I didn't clear out the directory properly before trying to create a workspace. Now, I have fully cleared the destination directory and I tried to create a workspace again and am faced with this error...

[image: error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! Here are the permissions for the workspace...

```
/Users/Shared $ ll
drwxrwxr-x  3 root         admin   102 Sep 18 19:45 myWorkspace
```

The trick is opening Eclipse as root. This is the command I use to do so...

```
// /Applications/Eclipse is the directory where eclipse.app lives
$ sudo /Applications/Eclipse/eclipse &
```

... and this runs an Eclipse instance as root and I can access the workspace from both accounts!

I can even still work with Git, however, I must do `sudo git [command]` every time... but I'm ok with that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it should; however, you might experience a blocking, if you open the project simultaneously in both accounts. Try to reset the access rights to 777 to determine, if it is a rights problem or a blocking problem:

```
chmod a+rwX /Users/HristoOskov/Sites/ -R
```

If you are able to add the project in both accounts now, make sure both accounts are in the admin-group and reset the group and rights to admin

```
chown .admin /Users/HristoOskov/Sites/ -R
chmod u=rwX,g=rwX,o=rX /Users/HristoOskov/Sites/
```

If you were not able to add it with the same message, reset the rights as stated above and make sure, that both accounts are in the admin-group. If not so, add both accounts and try again:

```
id Account1
id Account2
```

If in the result, any of the two accounts is not in the admin-group, you may add the account (in this example Account2) with the command

```
Add the user to the admin-group with the command /usr/sbin/dseditgroup -o edit -a Account2 -t user admin
```

Then restart above.

Comment: the `chown .admin` command doesn't work. it says `chown: admin: Invalid argument`

Comment: ah, sorry... syntax is a bit different in linux, I often get those mixed up. The corrent one is `chown :admin ...`

Comment: that syntax worked. workspaces still don't work. how do i check if both accounts are in the admin-group?

Comment: that is what the `id`-commands should do - unfortunatly, I don't have a mac here to test the commands. I've take the commands from my linux / unix-experience, but OS-X takes another way every now and then.

Comment: when I do `id HristoOskov`, I get `uid=501(HristoOskov) gid=20(staff) groups=20(staff)` plus other stuff

Comment: that means, that you are not in the admin-group and thus not having write-access to the directory, which you need. Add the user to the admin-group with the command `/usr/sbin/dseditgroup -o edit -a HristoOskov -t user admin` and do the same for the other admin user. Then restart the steps I layed out.

Comment: @Hristo let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2602/discussion-between-lars-and-hristo)

Answer (score 1):

Put the workspace in `/Users/Shared` and make sure both users have read/write access to the files (including Eclipse's special hidden directories).

Comment: How do I make sure both users have read/write access to the files in `/Users/Shared`? Shouldn't that be default?

Comment: I moved the dir to `/Users/Shared` and this is what it looks like... `drwxr-xr-x  4 dev          admin  136 Sep 17 03:24 myWorkspace`

Comment: It should be default, but it's good to check. As the workspace is a folder, just Get Info on the folder, go to "Sharing & Permissions", and make sure both user accounts (or "everyone") has read/write permissions.

Comment: From those permissions, it looks like only you (the "dev" user) have read/write. In the Get Info, Sharing & Permissions section, click the plus button, select the other user's user account in the chooser window, and set their Privilege to "Read & Write". Your Unix permissions after that should look like `drwxr-xr-x+` (note the plus at the end).

Comment: There seems to be another copy of Eclipse using the workspace. If eclipse isn't open in any user account, maybe the copy that you moved was initially copied while Eclipse was open?

Comment: I created the workspace from the `HristoOskov` account, then closed Eclipse, then switched to the `dev` account and opened Eclipse to that workspace and got the error. What do you suggest I do?

Comment: @Hristo Ask another question specifically covering that.

Comment: That is what my question is about... using the `/Users/Shared` hasn't worked for me :/

Comment: @Hristo Then make a new question that only asks about the Eclipse error, and phrase that question to cover only that error, not the multiple-users part. That will attract a different, new set of people who are more likely to be able to solve your problem.

Comment: @CajunLuke... gotcha, I misunderstood you the first time. Thanks for the suggestion :) Problem is though, this question is still left unanswered :/

Comment: @Hristo Maybe if you can get the Eclipse problem sorted, this question will be answered.

Comment: @CajunLuke... that's what I'm hoping for. I posted the question if you're curious... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465793/eclipse-workspace-in-use-or-cannot-be-created-chose-a-different-one