# Eclipse - "Workspace in use or cannot be created, chose a different one."

Tags: eclipse, workspace

I'm trying to create a workspace in the `/Users/Shared/` directory with the thought that I can share that workspace between users. The problem is that after I create the workspace and change the permission on it, I encounter the error below (image) **without even switching to a different user.**

I changed the permissions from

```
/Users/Shared $ ll
drwxr-xr-x  3 HristoOskov  wheel   102 Sep 18 20:07 myWorkspace
```

... to...

```
/Users/Shared $ ll
drwxrwxr-x  3 root         admin   102 Sep 18 19:45 myWorkspace
```

So what am I doing wrong here? How should I configure this workspace so that I can 1. get rid of the error message and 2. access it from both accounts without seeing the error message?

By the way, I'm working on Mac OS X Lion v10.7.1.

[image: error]

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489322/eclipse-says-workspace-in-use-or-cannot-be-created-chose-a-different-one-ho

Answer (score 502, accepted):

Right answer can be found in this (duplicate) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489322/eclipse-says-workspace-in-use-or-cannot-be-created-chose-a-different-one-ho).

I reproduced the answer here (and it works!):

> Just delete the .lock file in the .metadata directory in your eclipse
>   workspace directory

Comment: This should somehow be easier - how about it checks on startup and gives the option to remove the lock? It'd save 6000+ people a bit of trouble...

Comment: It helped 6000+ people but didn't solve for me :( any ideas?

Comment: Solved! I simply needed to run Eclipse with Admin permissions!

Comment: I didn't got the .metadata folder in my workspace I removed it from terminal and it really worked thanks.....

Comment: In my case, it was file permission issue. When I change owner of workspace directory, it worked.

Comment: Would like to share one more solution as found in https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/90961/, in which it changed the config to suspend the locking.

Answer (score 42):

I've seen 3 other fixes so far:

1. in .metadata/, rm .lock file
2. if 1) doesn't work, try end process javaw.exe etc. to exit the IDE
3. if 1)&2) doesn't work, try rm .log file in .metadata/, and double check .plugin/.
4. This always worked for me: relocate .metadata/, open and close eclipse, then overwrite .metadata back

The solution boils down to clean up the .metadata folder with correct contents

Comment: Ending the javaw.exe process and restarting Eclipse worked for me.

Comment: removing .metadata/.log fixed it for me

Comment: Killing the process was the only thing that worked for me.

Comment: 4 is working for me. I was using Citrix remote eclipse and deleting .lock from .metadata OR ending javaw.exe process was not working for me.

Answer (score 18):

Sometimes deleting the .lock file does not work. You can try this:

Remove *RECENT_WORKSPACES* line from *eclipse/configuration/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs*

Comment: excellent solution. I host eclipse on a removable drive and when the drive letter changes, this is the solution that will fix it.

Comment: This did it for me. On Mac the file to edit is /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/configuration/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs

Answer (score 13):

**for windows users**: In case of you can't remove `.lock` file and it gives you the following:

[image]

And you know that eclipse is already closed, just open **Task Manager** then **processes** then `end precess` for all **eclipse.exe** occurrences in the processes list.

Comment: And Java too (javaw).

Comment: @LucasMalor in my case it wasn't exist, but good addition, may be someone will need it, thanks

Answer (score 6):

Workspaces can only be open in one copy of eclipse at once. Further, you took away your own write access from the looks of it. All the users in question have to have the 'admin' group for what you did to even work a little.

Comment: Well, the one copy of Eclipse is easily solvable... I'll close it in UserA and open a new instance in UserB. Regarding the `admin`, I am an administrative user on my computer. Granted I don't understand much about these user groups, but I think being an admin should work. I just changed some stuff and it seems like the problem is not `admin`, its `root`.

Comment: Running eclipse again in Administrator rights made it work again, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Running eclipse in `Administrator Mode` fixed it for me. You can do this by *[Right Click] -> Run as Administrator* on the `eclipse.exe` from your install dir.

I was on a working environment with win7 machine having restrictive permission. I also did remove the `.lock` and `.log` files but that did not help. It can be a combination of all as well that made it work.

Answer (score 1):

An additional reason could be that you're pointing to a workspace on a drive that no longer exists, thinking that you're choosing the valid one. For instance, for me the workspace used to exist on the F drive, but now it is on my D drive. Even though I don't have the F drive anymore it is still listed as a workspace I once used during Eclipse startup. When I choose this old workspace Eclipse complains that the workspace is "in use", which is very strange.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this occurred on a test instance of Eclipse run from my main Eclipse session during plugin development. An error caused the gui to disappear, but didn't totally kill it. Hitting the stop button in the console took care of it.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have enough rights to workspace directory. I got this error when I didn't have write permission to workspace.

Answer (score -1):

Go to TaskManager(Right Click in the Task Bar) and select Processess menu bar and select eclipse.exe and Click EndProcess

Comment: Did he say he is running Windows?