# Eclipse says: “Workspace in use or cannot be created, chose a different one.” How do I unlock a workspace?

Tags: eclipse

When I start, Eclipse says "Workspace Cannot Be Locked"

"Could not launch the product because the associated workspace is currently in use by another Eclipse application." or “Workspace in use or cannot be created, chose a different one.”

But I know it isn't.

How do I "unlock" it?

Answer (score 610, accepted):

Just delete the `.lock` file in the `.metadata` directory in your eclipse workspace directory.

**Precaution** - If you delete the `.metadata` folder  all preference will be deleted.

Comment: I cant seem to delete it as it says its already open in eclipse, when its really not open...

Comment: Look if there is any process related to eclipse running in the background and kill it.

Comment: Thanks Boris! Not the right place, but I have to rant now.. Why doesn't Eclipse give an option to delete the .lock file or even hint at its existence? What self-respecting IDE can't have multiple instances running in the same workspace anyway? If deleting the .lock file is the only solution, why doesn't Eclipse delete it upon start-up after checking that no other instances are running? Come to think of it, the .lock file would then become obsolete instantly! Lastly,  other editors are in no way blocked from opening files in the workspace so its useless to begin with. I truly hate you Eclipse!

Comment: poluss86: and how would you check for other instances, especially, for example, when the workspace is on a network share?

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato Not :) Multiple clients sharing a single workspace on a network share is a horrible setup that screams for a version control system. For local usage this is obviously not an issue.

Comment: if you end eclipse, rm .lock, and reopen eclipse you'll get the same msg and you can see the file reappear inside the file explorer. I wanna know why it thinks it needs to have this(?)

Comment: @Cody Eclipse will fail to start if the .lock file exists, if it doesn't exist it will be created. I had the same problem as you are describing (rm .lock but still failure to start) and my solution was to rm Eclipse instead :)

Comment: @Cody Don't know if Eclipse usage is mandatory in your case; if not, I'd strongly recommend looking at another IDE. I've switched to Netbeans and haven't regretted that decision once. It's probably save to say that even a rusty razor would be a good alternative to Eclipse.

Comment: The ``.lock`` file is a hidden file, so if you go looking for it with ``ls``, don't forget the ``-a`` option: ``ls -a .metadata``.

Comment: Before removing a lock file, make sure the old eclipse process is indeed dead as you think

Comment: I'm back again for a fast resolution to what could become a frustrating problem. Since this isn't locked from commenting I'm going to spam and THANK YOU!!! anyway =)

Comment: But I need to delete the .lock file every time I open eclipse. Is not there any permanent solution available ?

Comment: Is there no permanent solution for this? It keeps happening on my Mac every time I restart.

Comment: If you are using a Mac, it probably caused by Folder permission setting. Run command `sudo chown -R yourMacUserID /your workspace directory/`, and then open the workspace with Eclipse, everything will work like a charm.

Answer (score 43):

I've seen 3 other fixes so far:

1. in .metadata/, rm .lock file
2. if #1 doesn't work, try killing the process javaw.exe etc. then rm .lock file
3. if #1 and #2 don't work, try rm .log file in .metadata/, and double check .plugin/.
4. This has always worked for me: relocate .metadata/, open and close eclipse, then overwrite .metadata back

The solution boils down to cleaning up the .metadata folder.

Comment: ...Except, if your .metadata folder has any custom company plugin data, that will now get "reset" back to the default version of data that you get if the plugin has never before been used with Eclipse.

Answer (score 18):

Go to TaskManager(Right Click in the Task Bar) and select Processess menu bar and select eclipse.exe and Click EndProcess

Comment: I was using STS so, I killed STS.exe

Answer (score 12):

Another possible cause of the “Workspace in use or cannot be created, chose a different one” issue is that **the real path to your workspace may have changed**.

In my case, the real location of the workspace had changed, but I had used a symlink to make it look like it was in the same location.  I saw errors in logs indicating that eclipse was looking at the previous "real" location, as opposed to following the symlink, and this was causing the errors.

In my case, I just moved the workspace back to its old location.

Comment: Had a similar case on Windows: My colleagues developed on drive D:, but I only had C:, so I just used SUBST D: C:\ and could use the workspace. Next day (next login), Windows had forgotten my SUBST of course and I got the error message.

Answer (score 7):

There is another case where the path to the workspace may not exist, e.g., if you have imported preferences from another workspace, then some imported workspace addresses may appear in your "open workspace" dialog; then if you didn't pay attention to those addresses, you would get the exact same error once you tried to open them.

Answer (score 7):

Running eclipse in `Administrator Mode` fixed it for me. You can do this by *[Right Click] -> Run as Administrator* on the `eclipse.exe` from your install dir.

I was on a working environment with win7 machine having restrictive permission. I also did remove the `.lock` and `.log` files but that did not help. It can be a combination of all as well that made it work.

Comment: So simple, and yet just what I needed!  In Linux run from command line:  `sudo eclipse`

Answer (score 3):

deleting logs and .lock didn't work but

**-clean** option fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

At times, if you are on Windows, you may not see all the processes - or the culprit process in Task manager. I had to click 'Show process from all users' and there was this java.exe that I had to kill in order to get back my workspace.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible case if none works is to see that there is a running `Java` application . may  be your previous open and close has left unkilled java instances.

1. Do look for any java instance is running if there are two at least you need to kill one.But ,most of the time i kill any java running :) because that java is using the work space earlier and still will if don't kill it.
2. Change another work space in case if you want a multiple IDE to use and work on diffrent or same project , but you should import project form workspace after you open your IDE.

Answer (score 2):

i was faced this issue when ever the eclipse is not closed (kill eclipse process the from task manager or computer power off), i was tried below steps, it worked for me.

1) Remove the file names start with ".fileTable" from this folder

> C:\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi.manager

2) Remove the log files like text files start with numeric names from this folder

> C:\eclipse\configuration

3) Open Command prompt(cmd) navigate to this folder

> C:\eclipse

type below command

> eclipse clean start

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For Mac Users:

It could be that another instance of eclipse is running in the background. If so, use either Force Quit eclipse or

```
ps -ef |grep eclipse
kill -9 pid
```

to all the eclipse instances, and start the new workspace

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You saved me!

Answer (score 2):

Start Eclipse with the option `-Dosgi.locking=none`.

I got the trick [here](https://joeywhelan.blogspot.com/2016/03/eclipse-hangs-on-start-up-workspace-on.html) and it works.

Don't do this unless you know nobody can work on the same file at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

PLease try to end task Eclipse from taskbar. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The answer @Boris gave is correct 99% of the time, however it can also happen if you open the workspace in an older version of Eclipse. A workspace imported into/created with Juno will throw this error when opened in Galileo.

Answer (score 0):

Another all-too-common reason for this problem is if you attempt to load a directory on a drive that is no longer connected. For example, Say you program in C:\Code\Java, but occasionally work off of a flash drive, H:\Code\Java. If you do not have the drive connected it can be easy to believe you are trying to load a valid directory without noticing your typo.

Answer (score 0):

Another problem is when eclipse doesn't have write access to your src folder. Change the security permission and make sure "Authenticated Users" are added with all permissions checked but Full Control & Special Permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error after I restarted the system (after a long time. Normally I just make it sleep).
Found out that once I mounted the drives (by clicking and opening it) where project folder is located, and relaunching eclipse, solved the issue for me.

PS: I'm an ubuntu user.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few steps to solve it the no. 4 step is works for me.

1. Delete .log files along .metadata folder.
2. Check the current user permission make sure to check the full control checkbox click apply then OK.
3. If you run system drive defragmentation or maintenance before you run eclipse editor sometimes original file path are not in their respective path to make sure run "previous version" time before your system maintenance of your drive where the eclipse workbench or something similar to this was saved.
4. This last option is works for me.
   Check the drive letter of your current drive where the code editor was saved. If something unusual e.g before your maintenance your drive letter is K then after defragment or maintenance. 
   The drive letter is now L hence you should change the drive letter to its original one that is K.
   to do this click the ff:
   Open control panel
   System & security
   Administrative tools
   Computer management
   Disk management
   in disk mngt choose the Drive example L
   then right click > change drive letter & path > click remove > then ok, open it again then > click add and > choose your original drive letter for that drive then click ok. If you use your computer for a long period of time do restart first to refresh everything.

Comment: You could do a better format to your explanation. The last step is hard to read. Also you wrote 4 stop not 5 as you said

Answer (score 0):

Choosing a "different one" is actually a pretty easy solution.

I had been running Eclipse as an administrator (`sudo eclipse` from the command line) because the "workspace" folder was throwing the `Workspace in use or cannot be created…` error (and running as administrator seemed to be the only solution that fixed it).

A coworker (working on this same issue with me) wanted to run Eclipse by clicking on an icon.  So when he ran Eclipse, and the dialogue box came up with the choose your workspace, he just added a "2" to the end of "workspace".

This created  a new folder:  "workspace2".  Eclipse ran fine with that; and I haven’t had any of the locking problems since.

Answer (score 0):

It will occur when you not closed eclipse.exe correctly.

*Open Task manager->End task your eclipse->Now open eclipse.exe it will work.

Hope its help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I have observed one case when eclipse when in forced quit, or `Alt-f2 xkill`ed in linux, an attempt to immediately open eclipse shows that error. Even the metadat/.lock file is not present in that case. 
However it starts working after a span of about two minutes

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's the wrong but I solved by creating a directory directly in c drive(c:\dev) instead of from my home folder (c:\users\me\dev). But I don't have to thinks about it. In my case, it is fresh eclipse unziped instance. I am not able to see .matadata folder in eclipse folder. By God grace, I solved.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this was happening to me (with Photon) was easily fixed by changing an Eclipse general preference:

```
Window -> Preferences -> General: Uncheck: "Always run in background"
```

Once you make that change, whenever you shutdown Eclipse, it will no longer leave the javaw.exe process running in the background. I’m guessing this is a bug in Photon (or a bug with using the Amazon Corretto OpenJDK version of Java with Eclipse) that will one day be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, but for some reasons the `.lock` file in workspace was not getting deleted. Even creating a new workspace was also getting locked.

So what I did was cleaning the windows `temp` folder, the `%PREFETCH%` folder and `%TEMP%` locations. Restart the system and then it allowed to delete the `.lock` file.

Maybe it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your workspace is used in Java TM, Open task manager and close eclipse.exe and java TM process.

Answer (score 0):

What worked in my case was restarting the system. (ubuntu 20.04)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone have come here with a STM32Cube related issue, which apparently is based on Eclipse and has the same problem, none of the above suggestions worked for me, and here is how I fixed it, for Linux, although I suppose you can find the corresponding paths in Windows as well.

In the `$HOME` directory, go to `.eclipse/com.st.stm32cube.ide.../configuration/settings`

The file `org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs` contains few options including the recent workspace path, and whether it will prompt you to select a workspace at the startup. Either modify the path for `RECENT_WORKSPACES`, or enable `SHOW_WORKSPACE_SELECTION_DIALOG`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was a space right before the workspace's location  `C:\`. I removed that space and it was enough :)