# Is any body here had encounter "lock fail" in ECLIPSE?

Tags: eclipse

Is any body here had encounter "lock fail" in ECLIPSE? I also encounter this problem. Can anyone tell what the reason and how to solve this.

Answer (score 21):

right-click on your project -> show in the local terminal - > git bash 
 then make a `git pull` .

that's worked for me ( Oxygen2 Relase 4.7.2 )

Comment: then git bash is not installed I guess ?

Comment: happened to me again and using conssole git bash fixed it again

Answer (score 2):

Just delete the .lock file in the .metadata directory in your eclipse workspace directory.
[refer this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489322/eclipse-says-workspace-in-use-or-cannot-be-created-chose-a-different-one-ho)

Comment: I can't delete the .lock file. It says iI should close eclipse to delete the file, then I after closing eclipse I was able to delete it but when I start again my eclipse, the .lock file is restore.

Comment: Open your  task manager. Click details and close all the eclipse tasks.. then delete the .lock file it should work.

Comment: still the same. I've actually restart my pc to be sure no applications will be open. But still the same. I've tried using unlocker application but still the same. And also tried to delete it by using cmd but still restore whenever eclipse start. I really want to get the rid of it.

Comment: OP is not very specific about his issue. A lock fail error may occur on a Git repository, in that case this answer is of no use, because the linked post deals with locking the Eclipse workspace, which is something completely different.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old thread but, it might help someone.

Please check if you have two or more branches with the same name ignoring the case sensitivity.

deleting the duplicate-named branches solved the issue for me. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you are using tortoise svn tool than right click on your codebase folder and select tortoise svn cleanup. wait for completion and it should works...

Answer (score 0):

I tried with some Gitbash commands but it didn't solve my problem. but, Changing the workspace worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In STS, In GIT perspective , Right click on project, show terminal , "git stash" , then git pull solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

On your repo, if there are branches with duplicate names (non-case sensitive), then delete the duplicate branch and try fetching again, it should resolve the problem.