# Eclipse workspace will not load

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a Java project in an Eclipse workspace that I've been developing on for some time now.

Starting yesterday, I can't get open the workspace.  Eclipse starts okay - but after I select the workspace, the flash screen begins to load but then disappears.  According to the task manager, Eclipse is no longer running.  However, if I attempt to load the workspace again, I get an error message that the workspace is in use.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,
Tim

Comment: You may want to post your Eclipse version and platform.  Will it allow you to use another workplace?

Comment: Sorry - it's Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers, Kepler Service Release 2 - on a Windows platform.  Yes, I'm able to open other workspaces.

Comment: See if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8489380/2055998) applies to your case.

Comment: Well, you've gotten me on the right track.  It seems to be something with a plugin.  If I delete the plugins directory entirely, it opens up the workspace fine.  I'm just going to have to do a bit more trial-and-error to figure out which plugin is hosing it.

Comment: Yep.  What I did was replace the folders in the plugins directory until I identified the offending file.  It was the workbench.xmi file.  Once I replaced that with a newly-generated file, everything works again.  Thanks!