# Eclipse -"Workspace in use or cannot be created choose a different one"

Tags: java, eclipse

I am just trying to open my Eclipse workspace and am not able to do that.

Eclipse -"Workspace in use or cannot be created choose a different one".Even when i have deleted .lock file , Now what can i do?

Comment: .lock file? Which lock file?

Comment: yes, i am not running eclipse while working in eclipse @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: .lock file in workscape folder

Comment: i am just trying to open my workscape ,what am not able to do that.

Comment: Have you followed the recommendations to be found in answers to [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489322/eclipse-says-workspace-in-use-or-cannot-be-created-chose-a-different-one-ho)?

Comment: yes, but not able to get valid answer

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the third post in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489322/eclipse-says-workspace-in-use-or-cannot-be-created-chose-a-different-one-ho) thread and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: as i mentioned earlier that the solution which r referening to me , i already tried but nothing happened..!

Comment: Try going into configuration/settings/org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs and then change the RECENT_WORKSPACES file value to wherever your workspace is maybe?