# Eclipse. Saving workspace takes forever

Tags: java, eclipse

My problem is that after closing eclipse the saving workspace didn't finish even after two hours and make me cant do anything on eclipse at all. I checked in 
C:..\workspace.metadata.log and the error is :

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jdt.ui 4 10001 2016-12-25 12:51:13.037
!MESSAGE Internal Error
!STACK 1
Java Model Exception: Core Exception [code 3] Some characters cannot be mapped using "Cp1252" character encoding.
Either change the encoding or remove the characters which are not supported by the "Cp1252" character encoding.
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.DocumentAdapter.save(DocumentAdapter.java:474)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CommitWorkingCopyOperation.executeOperation(CommitWorkingCopyOperation.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:729)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2313)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.runOperation(JavaModelOperation.java:794)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit.commitWorkingCopy(CompilationUnit.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.wizards.NewTypeWizardPage.createType(NewTypeWizardPage.java:2233)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.NewClassCreationWizard.finishPage(NewClassCreationWizard.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.NewElementWizard$2.run(NewElementWizard.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BatchOperation.executeOperation(BatchOperation.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:729)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2313)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.run(JavaCore.java:5358)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.actions.WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.run(WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
Caused by: java.nio.charset.UnmappableCharacterException: Input length = 1
    at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.encode(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filebuffers.ResourceTextFileBuffer.commitFileBufferContent(ResourceTextFileBuffer.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filebuffers.ResourceFileBuffer.commit(ResourceFileBuffer.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.DocumentAdapter.save(DocumentAdapter.java:472)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Some characters cannot be mapped using "Cp1252" character encoding.
Either change the encoding or remove the characters which are not supported by the "Cp1252" character encoding.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filebuffers.ResourceTextFileBuffer.commitFileBufferContent(ResourceTextFileBuffer.java:378)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filebuffers.ResourceFileBuffer.commit(ResourceFileBuffer.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.DocumentAdapter.save(DocumentAdapter.java:472)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CommitWorkingCopyOperation.executeOperation(CommitWorkingCopyOperation.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:729)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2313)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.runOperation(JavaModelOperation.java:794)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit.commitWorkingCopy(CompilationUnit.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.wizards.NewTypeWizardPage.createType(NewTypeWizardPage.java:2233)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.NewClassCreationWizard.finishPage(NewClassCreationWizard.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.wizards.NewElementWizard$2.run(NewElementWizard.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BatchOperation.executeOperation(BatchOperation.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:729)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2313)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.run(JavaCore.java:5358)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.actions.WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.run(WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
Caused by: java.nio.charset.UnmappableCharacterException: Input length = 1
    at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.encode(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filebuffers.ResourceTextFileBuffer.commitFileBufferContent(ResourceTextFileBuffer.java:366)
    ... 16 more
```

The problem is I dont know how can i fixed it without opening eclipse (I cant because its saving workspace).

I'll be greatfull for help.

PS. Sorry for my english I'm not native speaker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In top menu of Eclipse  go to Window Menu

1. Windows Menu –> Preferences –> General (expand it) –> Workspace
   (click on it).
2. Look for a box “Text File Encoding”. Default will be
   “Cp1252″.
3. Change radio to select other and select “UTF-8″ from combo
   box.

[image: Text File Encoding]

After setting this UTF-8 encoding, you can use UTF-8 in your code. Now you won’t get the ‘CP1252 character encoding’ error.

Comment: But I can't open eclipse because when i try to i got error : "The default workspace is in use cannot be created. Please choose a different one. "

Comment: Ok, try: delete the `.lock` file in the `.metadata` directory in your eclipse workspace directory. Be careful to *only* delete the `.lock` file in that directory and *not* the entire `.metadata` directory (http://stackoverflow.com/a/8489380/1248974). After deleting the `.lock` file, try opening eclipse.