# Eclipse error when I launched it

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-photon

I have one problem with my Eclipse IDE. When I launched it, I have the error below :

[Click here to show error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvxeD.jpg)

I have already tried to reinstall Eclipse and to change folder of workspace but I have already this error.

Comment: Would [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489322) help?

Comment: I have already try to do this but nothing

Comment: do you have permission to write data on that path? check by creating a textfile and them delete

Comment: Please see the below answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489322/eclipse-says-workspace-in-use-or-cannot-be-created-chose-a-different-one-ho

Comment: @RaulVasi Yes I have the permission. Sagar P I have already try to do this

Comment: is ur workspace folder readonly?

Comment: If it's not read-only, is its location valid? *What location are you trying to use?*

Comment: I used My Document. The workspace is OK because on my laptop I don't have any problem but on my computer I have this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try starting eclipse through your command line. Try the following command

`eclipse -data c:/folder/of/your/workspace`

This will ensure eclipse starts up at the workspace folder you want and not the default.