# Eclipse - “Workspace in use or cannot be created, chose a different one.” even after I removed .lock

Tags: eclipse

I moved my workspace, moved it back, and now I get this error. The other [thread on this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465793/eclipse-workspace-in-use-or-cannot-be-created-chose-a-different-one) suggests I delete the .lock file from the .metadata folder, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the eclipse or java process is still running, even if you don't see any UI of Eclipse anymore. It might then still hold file locks or other OS specific resource locks.

Therefore please always kill all eclipse processes (and the related java processes) before trying to use a workspace again after a crash. If you are unsure about the processes, rebooting is the safe way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to launch Eclipse as Administrator. Probably you have a permissions problem

Answer (score 0):

in your commandline, run eclipse as:

```
eclipse -clean
```