# Everytime i run eclipse IDE, its asks me to choose a new workspace.

Tags: eclipse

Every-time i run Eclipse IDE for Java EE, its asks me to choose a new workspace. If i choose the same workspace, it prompts "Workspace at 'E:/Projects' in use or cannot be created. Choose a different one". How can I avoid this and run on the same workspace? Also, when i try to save the project, it prompts me with "The User Operation is waiting" and some set of operations go on for sometime and then eclipse hangs. When i restart the eclipse, i will have to change the workspace. Please let me know how can i handle this? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, you can open a secondary window by dragging a tab out to a blank region of the screen. You can't open another instance of the program, as the workspace gets locked by the first process. (There might be a Window->New Window option, but I don't have Eclipse installed so I can't check)

Comment: But when i am waiting for user operation to complete, i cant even click on windows tab. Workspace get locked even if i close the eclipse and restart it. Even if i restart the system, i cant access the same workspace which i was once using.

Comment: @user3631398 If you've incorrectly closed Eclipse, some of the lock files may still be there. Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465793/eclipse-workspace-in-use-or-cannot-be-created-chose-a-different-one) answer.

Comment: I force closed it. So checked out all the solutions with log, lock files. None of it worked for me.

Comment: @user3631398 So, you're saying that there is no .lock file? And you aren't running multiple instances? Just want to grasp the current situation.

Comment: I deleted the lock file and tried running eclipse with the same workspace. Eclipse didnt open at all. And I am not running multiple instances.

Comment: @user3631398 Sorry, can't help then.

Comment: The second part of my question has been solved. Now the problem is with my workspace. I can't work with the same workspace.

Comment: Found this in log file of my previous workspace. 
"!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 4 0 2014-05-17 11:16:29.628
!MESSAGE An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException"